# Grails auto recompile (hot recompile) issue (2.3.8)

Tags: grails, compilation

What could be the problem if your Grails project isn't auto recompiling files when you edit and save while the project is running? It seems when I stop the Grails and restart it, then it will recompile whatever I changed during the last itertion.

Comment: you are most likely not running forked?

Comment: That turned out to be it. What I can't figure out is that I had the forking clause in BuildConfig.groovy commented out for a few iterations when I was trying something but then when I uncommented it it still wouldn't recompile. So I actually restored the file from an older backup and it works. Weird.